# Using setTimeout with recursive promises

Tags: node.js, promise

I have the following code that waits for a transaction to get mined on the Ethereum blockchain.

```
function waitForMinedTransaction(txHash, tries = 1) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(txHash, function(err, res) {
      if (err) reject(err)
      if (res) resolve(res)

      // nothing yet (retry in 10 sec..)
      console.log(`Attempt #${ tries }...`)
      if (tries > 60) reject("max_tries_exceeded")
      setTimeout(function() { return waitForMinedTransaction(txHash, tries + 1) }, 10000)
    })
  })
}
```

The issue is that when the transaction is mined (e.g. after 10 tries), it never gets resolved. I'm sure this has something to do with `setTimeout` and the promise chain (where a Promise is `return`ed instead of `resolve`/`reject`ing the current promise) but need some pointers on fixing it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would suggest to embed the chaining logic *inside* the promise constructor callback.

Also make sure that when you resolve or reject, you exit the function to avoid the rest of the code being executed. So put a `return` before the calls to `resolve` and `reject`, not that a return value has any sense, but just to make sure the rest of the function's code is not executed:

```
function waitForMinedTransaction(txHash) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        (function attempt(triesLeft) {
            web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(txHash, function(err, res) {
                if (err) return reject(err);
                if (res) return resolve(res);
                if (!triesLeft) return reject("max_tries_exceeded");
                console.log(`No result. Attempts left: #${ triesLeft }...`);
                setTimeout(attempt.bind(null, triesLeft-1), 10000);
            });
        })(60); // number of retries if first time fails
    });
}
```

If you prefer to have new promises in the chain (like you attempted to do), then the trick is to resolve with the chained promise, i.e. with the return value of the the chained call:

```
function waitForMinedTransaction(txHash, triesLeft = 60) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        getTransactionReceipt(txHash, function(err, res) {
            if (err) return reject(err);
            if (res) return resolve(res);
            console.log(`No result. Attempts left: #${ triesLeft }...`);
            if (!triesLeft) return reject("max_tries_exceeded");
            setTimeout(_ => {
                resolve(waitForMinedTransaction(txHash, triesLeft-1));
            }, 10000);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I like how you were able to avoid bubbling up and resolving all those promises by encapsulating the recursive bit. I'll be using this solution but if you were to do it, how would you actually resolve all these promises in the original nested, recursive fashion?

Comment: I have added that as an alternative to my answer just now.

Comment: Wonderful, thank you. I assume `resolve(reject)` would reduce to `reject` as one would expect?

Comment: Yes, if the promise passed as argument to `resolve` rejects, then the final promise will also reject. This is a required behaviour by the [Promises/A+ specification, point 2.3§1](https://promisesaplus.com/#the-promise-resolution-procedure): *"...it attempts to make promise adopt the state of x..."*

Comment: Thanks, you saved my night!

Comment: Glad to hear it was useful to you, @Vitorlui